# Linked List - Command Line arguments

Tags: c, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I am trying to implement a program that builds a Linked List from the command line.
I have two functions, one that creates the list and one that prints it.
My issue is that the list when outputting the data from the list is doing it in reverse order? Why is this happening? What can I do? Thanks in advance!

```
struct      Node {
char*       namePtr_;
struct Node*    nextPtr_;
};
```

**Create List function**

```
 struct Node*   makeList    (int argc, char* argv[]) {
 struct Node*   list    = NULL; // Head
 struct Node*   end = NULL; 

if (argc <= 1) {
  return NULL;
}

 int        i;
 for(i = 1;  i < argc;  i++) {
   struct Node* newNode;
   newNode = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(list));
   newNode->namePtr_ = argv[i];
   newNode->nextPtr_ = list;
   list = newNode;
 }
  return(list);
}
```

**Display List Function**

```
void print (const struct Node* list){
    const struct Node*  run;
    run = list;
    while (run != NULL) {
      printf("%s\n", run->namePtr_);
      run = run->nextPtr_;
    }
  }
```

**Release Memory Function**

```
void release (struct Node* list){
  struct Node* head = list;
  free(head);
  free(head->namePtr_);
}
```

**Command Line Arguments**

```
./argList hello there !
```

**Output**

```
!
there
hello
```

Comment: `newNode->nextPtr_ = list;` inserts the new node at the head of the list. So the list look like `! -> there -> hello`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bug here

```
newNode = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(list));
```

`sizeof(list)` returns the size of a pointer, to get the size of the `struct` you want `sizeof(*list)`

And you are pushing, instead you need to enqueue (attach to to the tail, not to the head)

Here a [simple implementation](https://www.learn-c.org/en/Linked_lists)

Finally, do not `free(namePtr_)`, the arguments passed to `main` (`argv[x]`) are not reserved dinamically by your program, the rule is one `free` per `malloc`

Comment: Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You're replacing the head of the list with each new parameter, read from left to right. The last parameter is going to be your last head.

So when you're reading the list starting from the head down, the last parameter will be first, thus reversing the input arguments.